# ORM relationships in Kohana

Tags: orm, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have the following tables:

```
users           { id, name }
events          { id, name }
user_events     { id, date, user_id, event_id }
user_summaries  { id, user_id, event_id, qty }
```

Table `user_events` stores all user events (there are many of the same types at different times) and `user_summaries` stores how many of each type of events occured to each user. The former gets only `INSERT` queries and the latter mostly `UPDATE` ones.

Of course both `user_events` and `user_summaries` have foreign keys to link with `users` and `events` tables.
I want to represent this relation in my Models in Kohana. I have experience with foreign keys, but it's my first approach to both Kohana and ORM and I'm not sure really how to define my models there to represent these relations.

What I want to be able to do is basically this:

```
// I'm able to do this.
$user = ORM::factory('user', 1);
$user_events = $user->events->find_all();
$user_summaries = $user->usersummaries->find_all();

// I'm able to do this, too.
$event = ORM::factory('event', 1);
$event_users = $event->users->get_all();

// I don't know how to be able to do this:
$user_event = ORM::factory('userevent', 1);
$user_details = $user_event->user->find();
$event_details = $user_event->event->find();
```

My current models look like this:

```
# classes/model/user.php
class Model_User extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'scores'    => array(),
        'usersummaries' => array(),
    );
}

# classes/model/event.php
class Model_Event extends ORM
{
    protected $_has_many = array(
        'scores'        => array(),
        'usersummaries' => array(),
    );
}

# classes/model/userevent.php
class Model_Userevent extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'user'  => array(),
        'event' => array(),
    );
}

# classes/model/usersummary.php
class Model_Usersummary extends ORM
{
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'user'  => array(),
        'event' => array(),
    );
}
```

Currently calling:

```
$user_event = ORM::factory('userevent', 1);
$user_details = $user_event->user->find();
```

returns always the first user from `users` table, even though `userevent` has different user_id.
I presume I need to change something in `Model_userevent` but I'd use with some help.

NB. I'm using Kohana 3.0.8.

Comment: Use `$user_event->user` (without `find()`). Models look fine, but may be you should manually define related models for `usersummaries` and `userevents` relations (Ko3 inflector may works wrong for these names)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thank you, biakveron. Put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$user_event->user` (without `find()`). Models look fine, but may be you should manually define related models for `usersummaries` and `userevents` relations (Ko3 inflector may works wrong for these names)